# LVExtend can't find space on physical volume

Tags: partition, virtual-machine

I've been struggling for a while now to create more space in my VM, and I believe it's going wrong on the first step. I've increased the size of my physical volume, `sda3`;

```bsh
$ sudo lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop1                       7:1    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1434
loop2                       7:2    0  67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop3                       7:3    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop4                       7:4    0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14978
loop5                       7:5    0  44.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15534
sda                         8:0    0   500G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 498.5G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  48.5G  0 lvm  /
```

As you can see, `sda3` is roughly 500GB, but when I run LVExtend, it seems to disagree;

```bsh
$ sudo lvextend -L +100G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Insufficient free space: 25600 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

I already ran it once before and it only found a little space;

```bsh
$ sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from <24.64 GiB (6307 extents) to <48.50 GiB (12415 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edits:
Output of `pvs`:

```bsh
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <48.50g    0
```

Comment: What does `pvs` say? Did you run `pvresize` after resizing the `sda3` partition?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny Running `pvresize` did the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increased the size of `/dev/sda3` but you haven't yet told LVM that the size has increased. Use `pvresize /dev/sda3` to resize the Physical Volume. This will automatically grow space availabe in the Volume Group and you can then use `lvresize` to grow the Logical Volume. After that you'll need to resize the filesystem itself.

Growing the filesystem to 100% of the available LV space seems a little strange though. If that's all you're going to do then there's no point having the overhead of LVM; you might as well have just put the filesystem directly onto `/dev/sda3`.

Comment: Putting the FS on `sda3` isn't something I've consciously done myself, I believe ESXi set it up that way. Thanks for the elaboration, though!

Comment: ESXi doesn't use LVM. (It does use its own variant of logical volumes, though.) It might be a feature of the Ubuntu installer